# In a Windows + Wubi installed machine, I can't reach my files on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wubi

I have got Windows 7 on C Drive. 2 days ago I installed wubi. And it created a file named ubuntu. It was all okay so far. I began to use ubuntu and I used to reach the files that I have on D Drive. However something happened today I can't reach my D Drive on ubuntu. And interestingly I can reach my C Drive on ubuntu. That looks so weird. Please help if you have information to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but you can access you Windows Host drive (the one we Ubuntu directory is located) by using /host path in Ubuntu